# Well established Trilateration algorithms

Tags: algorithms

Are there any well established algorithms for finding an object's location in 3D space when we know its approximate distance to at least 3 known locations?

Trilateration seems to be a well understood and popular topic and yet the only algorithms I've found come from fringe academic papers. I'm looking for a widely accepted algorithm, if such a thing exists.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True-range_multilateration#Three_Cartesian_dimensions,_three_measured_slant_ranges, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True-range_multilateration#Redundant_range_measurements